# JavaScript implementing a function to not repeat everything in those blocks

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my application, I need to display multiple google maps. I have done this (http://jsbin.com/arepaj/1/edit) to display 2 maps, but I feel that it is kind of a dirty way using same structure many times. Because, I copied two times the same google maps elements to be able to display two maps.

How to create multiple google maps dynamically so that i can only pass the location coordinates to the function and create multiple maps. My biggest concern is here that how to create 'div' tags dynamically for displaying each map.

Answer (score 0):

You can make everything dynamic:

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ASmW2/1/embedded/result/)

```
function makeMap(lat,lng,zoom,type,index) {
    var elem =  document.createElement('div');
    elem.setAttribute('id','map'+index);
    elem.setAttribute('style',"width: 500px; height: 300px");
    document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(elem);
    var map = new google.maps.Map(elem,{
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(lat,lng),
        zoom: zoom,
        mapTypeId: type});
    return map;
}
```

You will have to add some functionality to let you put the maps where you want them on the page (this proof of concept just appends them to the body as they are created).

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a Maps API question, you have a JavaScript question. And it's a good question to ask.

The real question is: "I have two very similar blocks of JavaScript code. Is there a way to write this without repeating everything in those blocks?"

And the answer is "Yes! Put the repeated code in a function."

Taking your code from jsbin and making the simplest changes to move the code into a common function, you'd have something like this:

```
function createMap( id, lat, lng ) {
    var container = document.getElementById( id );
    var center = new google.maps.LatLng( lat, lng );

    var map = new google.maps.Map( container, {
        zoom: 10,
        center: center,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
}

 function initialize() {
    createMap( 'map_canvas', 48.1391265, 11.580186300000037 );
    createMap( 'map_canvas2', 46.702, 11.678 );
}
```

Of course you can extend it from there. Have something else that will be different from one map to the other? Just add another parameter to the function.