# Loading multiple google maps on a single page

Tags: javascript, html, performance, google-maps

I am trying to load multiple google maps on a single page, but page loading time is very high. How to speed up page loading time?

My example html code is below. Actually, below Google maps created in a loop and their number will be minimum 100.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>        
</head>

<body>          
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

    <div id="postid_78" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
        <script>                    
                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("postid_78"), mapProp);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    map: map
                });
        </script>                
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="postid_77" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
        <script>                    
                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("postid_77"), mapProp);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    map: map
                });
        </script>                
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="postid_76" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
        <script>                    
                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("postid_76"), mapProp);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    map: map
                });
        </script>                
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="postid_75" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
        <script>                    
                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("postid_75"), mapProp);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    map: map
                });
        </script>                
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="postid_74" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
        <script>                    
                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("postid_74"), mapProp);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    map: map
                });
        </script>                
    </div>
    <hr />
    <div id="postid_73" style="width:600px;height:150px;">
        <script>                    
                var mapProp = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    zoom: 5,
                    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                };
                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("postid_73"), mapProp);
                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: new google.maps.LatLng('42.5000', '1.5000'),
                    map: map
                });
        </script>                
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Instead of loading multiple maps, why don't you add multiple markers on a single map?

Comment: [100 maps doesn't take all that long for me](http://jsfiddle.net/q2yd2/4/), but will depend on your computer/browser. Modified from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919121/adding-multiple-map-canvases-to-window-google-maps-javascript-api-v3/24920602#24920602).

Comment: It needs to be multiple maps, it is design rule.

Answer (score 1):

To improve the page load speed you can (must) do several things.

1. Load the API asyncron [DOCUMENTATION HERE](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async?hl=es)
2. Only initialize the maps when they are visible in viewport
   Therefore you can use plugins [LIKE THIS](https://github.com/protonet/jquery.inview)
3. Also place your JS script always at the bottom of the body tag.
   So all the content get loaded and no javascript will deny the content load

This should realy increase the page load. I've done this on several projects and it works fine!