# How to insert google maps through a while loop?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-maps

I want to insert a **google map** in a **div**(html) which generates through a **while loop**. Google map gets coordinates from the database.

[It should appear as in this **image**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NBEjb.jpg)

Since I need to use a **google map api key**, I used following code.

But, It shows **a map**, **only in the first div**, **using the last coordinates** of the database, and doesn't show any other map in any other divs.

```
<?php 
    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');


    function currentUsers($connection){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);

        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $userID = $row['id'];
                $firstName = $row['firstname'];
                $country = $row['country'];
                $latitude = $row['latitude'];
                $longitude = $row['longitude'];

                echo '<div> 
                            <div align = "left">
                                <h3>'. $userID. " ". $firstName. " ". $country. '</h3>
                            </div>

                            <div id  = "map" align = "right">
                                <script>    <!--Google map api-->
                                  function initMap() {
                                    var x = '. $latitude. ';
                                    var y = '. $longitude. ';
                                    var myLatLng = {lat: x, lng: y};

                                    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\'map\'), {
                                      center: myLatLng,
                                      scrollwheel: true,
                                      zoom: 4
                                    });

                                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                      map: map,
                                      position: myLatLng,
                                      title: \'Hello World!\'
                                    });
                                  }
                                </script>
                                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
                            </div>  
                       </div>';
            }

        }else{
            echo "Currently there are no users!";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }

    currentUsers($connection);


?>

<html>
<head><title></title>
      <style> #map {width: 500px; height: 400px; } </style>  <!--Size of the map-->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

ID of each div should be unique. Try this

```
<?php 
        $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');


        function currentUsers($connection){
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM user ";
            $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
            $x= 0;
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                    $userID = $row['id'];
                    $firstName = $row['firstname'];
                    $country = $row['country'];
                    $latitude = $row['latitude'];
                    $longitude = $row['longitude'];

                    echo '<div> 
                                <div align = "left">
                                    <h3>'. $userID. " ". $firstName. " ". $country. '</h3>
                                </div>

                                <div id  = "map_'.$x.'" align = "right">
                                    <script>    <!--Google map api-->
                                      function initMap() {
                                        var x = '. $latitude. ';
                                        var y = '. $longitude. ';
                                        var myLatLng = {lat: x, lng: y};

                                        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_'.$x.'"), {
                                          center: myLatLng,
                                          scrollwheel: true,
                                          zoom: 4
                                        });

                                        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                          map: map,
                                          position: myLatLng,
                                          title: \'Hello World!\'
                                        });
                                      }
                                    </script>
                                    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?callback=initMap" async defer></script>
                                </div>  
                           </div>';
                           $x++;
                }

            }else{
                echo "Currently there are no users!";
            }

            mysqli_close($connection);
        }

        currentUsers($connection);


    ?>

    <html>
    <head><title></title>
          <style> #map {width: 500px; height: 400px; } </style>  <!--Size of the map-->
    </head>
    <body></body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Thank you for the response. But It doesn't work. Now, it doesn't load any map. It seems that API doesn't allow multiple maps to load..

Answer (score 0):

1. You can only reliably include the API once.  Currently you are including the API for each map you add.
2. You can also only have one function with the name `initMap`, currently you are including multiple versions of that function.
3. You can only have one div with id="map", currently you have one for each location.

related question (javascript only, no PHP): [Adding multiple map canvases to window - Google Maps Javascript API v3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24919121/adding-multiple-map-canvases-to-window-google-maps-javascript-api-v3)

Answer (score 0):

This is 100% working for me i've tested this code

```
<?php
$arr='';
$connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'users');


    function currentUsers($connection){
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM user";
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $sql);
        $x= 0;
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
            while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                $userID = $row['id'];
                $firstName = $row['firstname'];
                $country = $row['country'];
                $arr[] = array($row['latitude'],$row['longitude'],$x);
                echo '<div style="width:100%;"> 
                            <div style="width:250px; height: 150px; float :left;">
                                <h3>'. $userID. ". ". $firstName. " ". $country. '</h3>
                            </div>
                            <div id  = "map_'.$x.'"  style="width:250px;height: 150px;">   </div>
                      </div>';
                       $x++;
            }
        echo '<script> var mymaps ='.json_encode($arr).'</script>';

        }else{
            echo "Currently there are no users!";
        }

        mysqli_close($connection);
    }
    currentUsers($connection);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js"></script>

<script>
var maps = []; 

function initialize(id, myLatLng) { 
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 9,
        center: myLatLng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    maps[id] = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_'+id), 
        mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
       map: maps[id],
       position: myLatLng,
       title: 'Hello World!'
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    for( var i = 0; i < mymaps.length; i++)
    {
        var x = parseFloat(mymaps[i][0]);
        var y = parseFloat(mymaps[i][1]);
        var myLatLng = {lat: x, lng: y};
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize(mymaps[i][2],myLatLng)); // two calls
    }

});
</script>
```

[image: Here is the output]